# Dystopian Sci-fi Biodomes Movie

Tags: story-identification, movie, dystopia

I'm trying to track down what I think was a movie I watched on British TV as a kid in the mid-early 90s.

The key scene I remember is a young girl (maybe 6-10) and an older man (grandad age). They live under a futuristic biodome in almost American looking (wooden?) buildings. The scene I remember is in a hanger/barn with a small plane/vehicle (I remember it as an old looking plane with top and bottom parts to the wings) that the granddad is working on/fixing while the girl is sat on a rafter or something similar over head. It was just the two of them living there, and no one else lived nearby.

There may or may not have been a robot or dog companion. The man may or may not have been her granddad, and her mother may or may not have been a resistance fighter of some kind. I feel like there were strong dystopian vibes but I can't remember enough I am certain about to put that into better context without just confusing it more.

I remember it alongside Logan's Run, Silent Runnings and the Andromeda Effect and it has a similar feel to them.

Edit with further info: the movie was in English but it might have been American, was live action and it is likely it was shown on daytime TV during the 90s.
It had a dated feel.
The characters were white, and from what I remember fairly stereotypical in appearance.
I believe the plane was a biplane.
I think the movie was in colour but it could've been black and white.
I don't quite remember what the biodome looked like (eg was it round) but it was some kind of artificial covering their house, barn and farm were under and protected them from the outside air. The little girl being told the outside air was "bad" may have been a key element in the story, I can't remember if it later turned out it was safe to breath.
I think but am not confident that there was an authoritarian style bad guy element.
I believe, but may be wrong, that the little girl had some kind of dungarees on.

I am so sorry for the lack of certainty, I was so young when I saw it and I've spent so long trying to remember it, I am fairly confident the details have got a little warped so if it even sounds half like anything else, that could be it!

There is even a very slim chance it was a novel not a movie, and it just feels so vivid I am mistaking it for a movie.